# How to connect different databases like Mysql and oracle having same schema, table name and data in spring boot using JPA?

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, spring-boot, jpa

I want to connect 2 different database Mysql and Oracle having same schema, table and data in spring boot JPA. I've configure properties file with 2 different data sources with respective database configuration but i am stuck how to access properties of second data source.

Comment: You need more details - sounds like you've defined two separate datasources within your application that you want to have working concurrently in the same app. If so, now you need to figure out how you want the app to use those datasources. How to handle switching if given an Entity, say Person, what persistence context (and so datasource) to use for that data. There are many ways to handle it; maybe create two persistence contexts and use other information (like headers) to determine where the data goes or is queried from.

Comment: @Chris Suppose i have table "person" having column id, name, age, city as id is primary key column. This table exist on 2 database oracle and Mysql, My task is to create service in spring boot and insert record on person table in both database with single request using JPA. As well fetch record which is from 1 table because table on both databases have same records.

Comment: You need a lot more. If you are inserting a record in both databases - do they need to be in the same transaction? You are going to have to create two separate persistence units and handle the save of the Person instance into both (manually make separate calls into both using your own Repository/Service wrappers), but if you need them in the same transaction, you'll have to look into distributed transactions - there are tutorials on this.